# Do I really need the @rails3 when creating a gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm confused, what does the @rails3 do when creating a new gemset?

I want to run both rails2.1.1 and rails3 applications, and switch between the two.

I create a rvm for 1.9.2 and 1.8.7

And inside 1.9.2 I created 2 gemsets, and installed rails 2.1.1  in one gemset, and rails3 in another gemset.

Am I doing this right?

I'm reading others use the @rails3 in the gemset creation process, and it helps isolate things?? Can someone explain this as I don't get it.

Should I delete the gemsets and start over? or is it higher up that I have to delete?

Comment: by the way, i added some comment on your other thread about Rails 2.1.1 and 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

There are rubies and gemsets. 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 are your rubies. Each ruby version can have many gemsets (each gemset is tied to one ruby install on your rvm). Personally, I have created a new gemset for each new project to help isolate the gems needed for that project from any other project.

Comment: what does the gem install rails -pre do?  i.e. what does the switch 0-pre do?

Comment: gem install rails --pre #installs latest beta of the rails gem

Answer (score 0):

rails is a gem, so it is usually recommended to isolate it and all the gems it depend on into a gemset.

otherwise, you can also use

```
rails _2.1.1_ -v
```

to invoke rails 2.1.1, although the usual recommendation is to create separate gemsets.  You can see a lot of info of the gems by `rvm info`, and `rvm list gemsets`.  Each gemset is a separate folder and keep things isolated from each other quite well.